# How to test if a variable contains special characters other than numbers , letters and # and _ and $?

Tags: oracle, plsql

There is a variable representing a string :

```
create or replace procedure create_user(login varchar2)
is
begin
    execute immediate 'create user "' || login || '" identified by 1 default tablespace tbs_sse';
    execute immediate 'grant create session to "' || login || '"';
    execute immediate 'grant select any sequence to "' || login || '"';
end;
```

How to test if the variable `login` contains special characters other than numbers , letters and # and _ and $ ?

Comment: Remove the double quotes around `login`, then invalid usernames will be rejected anyway.

Comment: I need these double quotes to manage invalid characters.

Comment: What are these invalid characters if they are not "special characters other than numbers, letters, `#`, `_` and `$`"? By default Oracle will reject user names containing invalid characters. Why double-quote them if you don't want to allow normally invalid characters?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - double quotes are used for specific letter case, not just to include special characters in names. If a table was defined (using double-quotes) as `"Test_Table", if you search for it without double-quotes you will not find it, even though it contains no special characters.

Comment: ... with that said, though, it is probably better IN THIS CONTEXT to do away with the double-quotes. If a user wants to give himself the username `John`, create the user `JOHN` in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just you can check using regexp. Create your regexp based on what you are expecting.

```
SELECT  count(1) into counter 
FROM    dual
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE (LOGIN_VAR , '^[a-zA-Z0-9_$#]+$');

IF (counter != 0) THEN
    --Invalid Login alert, error return
END IF;
```

For more idea about oracle object naming rules please check [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51109)

Comment: Why do you need to select from dual into a variable in PL/SQL? You can write the condition directly in the IF statement.

Comment: @mathguy Aah. Thank you for the tip. Old habits, i always go for the query with dual!! I will try to change that. It causes unnecessary context-switch & increases load !!

Answer (score 1):

You test - probably - in an IF statement. If so, you can use something like

```
........
if regexp_like(login, '[^a-zA-Z0-9_#$]')
then ........
........
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your *actual* purpose is to check that the name is suitable as an Oracle identifier, you're probably better off using the built-in function `dbms_assert.simple_sql_name`, e.g.:

```
  dbms_assert.simple_sql_name(login);
  execute immediate 'create user "' || login ...
```

This will raise `ORA-44003 string is not a simple SQL name` if `login` has an unsuitable value.